# String comparison using in doesn't work with unless

Tags: string, conditional-statements, puppet

I want to check, if a given string is inside an array and if it isn't, I want to execute the code inside.
However the in function seems to work with if only, when I use unless I get the following error.

```
Could not parse for environment production: Syntax error at 'in'; expected '}'
```

Code looks like this:

```
$string = 'abc'
$array = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']

unless $string in $array {
  do xxx
}
```

what is going on? I use Puppet 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works with Puppet `3.7`.

`2.7` seems to have no `unless` at all.

Try an `if ! x` construct, or work around the issue using

```
if $foo in $bar {
    # noop
} else {
    # your code here
}
```